# Update only one attribute on database with android

Tags: android, cakephp

I am developing an android app using cakephp in backend. I have a database table with 20 attributes, say xx. I already developed relevant rest api. Using postman everything works perfectly. On android I have a question!

What if I want to update only one attribute of one record for my xx table ? From android, should I post all the data again? If not how can I update only that attribute using the id of the record from AsyncTask?

**UPDATE**

this an example of my code :

```
public class AsycTaskManager {

    public static class AddFlightPlan extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String result ;
        Car car = new Car();
        String token ;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            car = params[0];
            token = params[1];
            String editCar = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/backend/0/cars/"+car.id+"/editcar";

            URL object = null;
            try {
                object = new URL(editCar);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
                con.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
               JSONObject cred = new JSONObject();
               cred.put("name", car.name);
               cred.put("description",car.desc);
               cred.put("code", car.code);
               cred.put("date", car.date);
               cred.put("guid", car.guid);
               cred.put("baggage_code", car.bag_code);
               cred.put("baggage_weight",car.bag_weight);
               cred.put("max_speed", car.max_speed);

                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(cred.toString());
                wr.flush();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode();
                if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                   JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                    Log.e("result","f"+sb.toString());
                    if (sb.toString() != null) {
                        return sb.toString();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.e("result","null "+result);
        }
    }
}
```

and for example I want to update only the name

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: so far I have a form, once I want to update a field , I post all the data again so I don't think that's the right thing to do since I'm only updating one attribute

Comment: @chogath Can you post some code which you have tried?

Comment: I can see overall picture of your question. But, it wasn't accurate. So, you can try something like `$yourObj = $this->YourModel->findById("yourId");` Then, you can update anything you want. There are so many other approach to try it. You can use whatever you comfortable to use.

Comment: on the php side it's fine . using postman I can update only the name using the id , it works fine! my problem is how to update only one attribute with android without posting all the data

Comment: as you can see I'm passing an object as a params to the AsyncTask

Comment: I guess if you are using req type patch then there is no need to create JSON object with all information,  pass only updated field and row id in your JSON. Then in your backend code extract that id and field and make update query in row id with extracted field.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do but my question is if i have 40 attributes how can I know which filed were updated !!